# How to get a System.Drawing.Image object from image which build action is marked as Resource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf app,and got a image useful for codebehind which's location in the project is something like "projectName\images\pp.png" and its build action is "Resource"(Node:**not Embedded Resource**).
I need a System.Drawing.Image object in the codebehind.
I tried these methods:

1.

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\images\pp.png", UriKind.Relative));
var stream = img.StreamSource;
System.Drawing.Image needObj = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

i got a null stream,so it's not work.

2.

```
private static System.IO.Stream getResource(string name)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string resName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName);
}
var stream = getResource(@"\images\pp.png");
System.Drawing.Image needObj = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

i got an UnmanagedMemoryStream object,and an InvalidArgument exception occurred while calling "Image.FromStream(stream)" .

Could anyone tell me why the two methods above not working or how to achieve it ?

Comment: If it's done right, the resource is a `Bitmap` which can be directly assigned to an `Image` variable.

Comment: Did the problem resolved?

Comment: @eforlina Ok, Got it, resource, not embedded resource. So ints better to remove winforms tag, because resource is only for wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WPF - Get an Image Resource and Convert to System.Drawing.Image**

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/"
    + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    + ";component/"
    + "images/pp.png", UriKind.Absolute));

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)bitmapImage));
var stream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Save(stream);
stream.Flush();
var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
```

**Note:**

- Use "/" instead of "\"
- Consider reading [Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx) (important part: Resource File Pack URIs)
- Add reference to system.drawing.dll

> **Local Assembly Resource File**
>
> The pack URI for a resource file that is compiled into the local
>   assembly uses the following authority and path:
>   `pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.Ext`

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Forms - Get an image embedded resource:**

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream= assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourAssemblyName.images.pp.png");
var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

**Note:**

- `"YourAssemblyName.images.pp.png"` is case sensitive
- Instead of `YourAssemblyName` put your assembly name, for example for my project, it is my project name and also my default namespace.
- If you are not sure what exactly pass to `GetManifestResourceStram` use the code below:

**Find embedded resource names:**

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
        .Where(x => x.EndsWith("pp.png")) //Comment this line to find all resource names
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(resource =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(resource);
        });
```

Comment: :It's not work.It's easy to get a `BitmapImage` object.What I need is a `System.Drawing.Image` object.By the way,`BitmapImage.StreamSource` always been null,which confused me also.