# How to show relative source image on WPF hosted by WinForm Project without modifying behind code?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I made WinForm project and add ElementHost for using WPF blend effect on some Images.

```
ElementHost m_host = new ElementHost();
WPF_TK4S wpfTK4S = new WPF_TK4S();
m_host.Child = wpfTK4S;
m_host.Size = new Size(1000, 1000);
m_host.Location = new Point(0, 0);
this.Controls.Add(m_host);
```

I added the image control on WPF user control like below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.WPF_TK4S"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1000">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Image Source="/Resources/TK4S_254X253.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="344" Margin="48,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342" Stretch="None"/>
</Grid>
```

The image is shown well on control view but is now shown when I run the application.
Fortunately, after I changed the source uri into absolute uri like

```
"D://Visual Project/Test/Test/Resources/TK4S_254X253.png"
```

the image is shown well!!
I tried to use all kinds of relative uri like

```
".../Test/Resources/TK4S_254X253.png", "pack://application:,,,/TK4S_254X253.png"
```

but it is not work.
I need to use relative path because the project is operating on Server so every project paths are different. And I have to use this things on xaml because I have to use blend after the image is initialized. 
Does anything I need to know other option?

Comment: Did you try `Source="./Resources/TK4S_254X253.png"`? It should work, provided that it is a valid relative path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

Comment: Sure. But It does not work. It is naturally well on WPF project but It seems like It is not recognize the relative path on winform project using wpf host control.

Comment: [How to get a System.Drawing.Image object from image which build action is marked as Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32486679/3110834)